# armstrong no. program ( local variable z may not have been initiated )

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class test15{

public static void main(String ...NR){  

int sum=0;  

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int x,y,z;

System.out.println("Enter the number");

int num = sc.nextInt(); 

num = z;

while(num!=0){


x = num%10;

sum = sum + x*x*x;

num = num/10;

}   


if(sum == z){

    System.out.println("no is armstrong");  

}

else{

    System.out.println("no is not armstrong");

}

}


}
```

// getting error local variable Z may not have been initialized so how to make a variable which user input equals to another then ? i am  new to java.

Comment: The error says it all... You have not initialized `z`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the concept of default values is applied to only instance variable so in your class the variable z is a local variable which means you need to initialize it before using it.

So in here `int x,y,z;` z is not initialized to any value yet and then in here `num = z;` you are trying to assign the value of `z` to `num` which(`z`) was never initialized to any value what I think is you might want to do the opposite way that means `z=num` in this case the user input num will be assigned to z.

either initialize local variables before using somewhere else like

```
int x =0;
int y =0;
int z =0;
```

Or in your case just this should do the work

```
z = num;
```

Answer (score 0):

local variables (i.e. variables defined within methods) must be initialized before their value is accessed.

You can, for example, do it when you define `z` :

`int z = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Basically the LHS = RHS the value of RHS is assigned to LHS.
In you case you have code as

```
 int z;
 num = z;
```

Here you can seed that z is not initialized.

I believe you wanted to do

```
z=num;
```

So that the value you num goes into z.